# Reading actual work via PSI web services (Project Server 2007)

Tags: project-server, psi

I want to read the approved actual work via the Project Server Interface (PSI) on a Project Server 2007

I stumbled upon the ReadStatusTimephasedData function on the PSIStatusing namespace. This does exactly what I want, EXCEPT: It gives me the actual work as entered by the project member in the pwa. It is not the approved actual work after the project manager approves it.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-10);
DateTime end = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5);
long interval = 1 * 24 * 60; //one day

PSIStatusing.StatusingTimephasedActualsDataSet actualsDs = statusService.ReadStatusTimephasedData(projectGuid, assignGuid, start, end, interval);
```

HOw do I get the approved actual work? Has anyboy a hint? I'd be very glad if you can help me

Markus

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question can get complicated in a hurry.
The "approved actual work" is added to the project plan. For the assignments in the project plan, the actual work is changed to match the newly approved data. The PSI can get at this data, but not with the timephased characteristic. That is, totals per assignment, not by day.

But here's the big catch: depending on server configuration the project manager may have the ability to edit this work after it is approved. If the server is not set up to limit this action, then there is no way to determine what work was approved. On the other hand, if the server is set up to restrict a project manager's ability to edit this data, then it can be found (after a project publish) in the _Reporting database, in the AssignmentByDay tables.

The easiest pieces to get that are close to this are the

- time entered by resources on timesheets.
- published Actual Work, whether from resources or editted by the project
  manager.

Hope this helps, and is what you were after.

Let me know if you have questions on this...
James Fraser